# Extract a section in other file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to extract a section ModeName

I am using the following example code using get function

```
test_dict = {
    "ModeName":1, "Measurement",
    }

x = test_dict.get("ModeName")
print(x)
```

The above function just gives me 1. Is there any way to get complete ModeName?

Comment: Its not possible in your example because of the way you created `test_dict`. How do you load the actual cna file? Can you please add that code?

Comment: I actually parse it as a dictionary. I wanted to know a function which can extract complete section.

Comment: Then you probably have to change the way you parse it. Its not that diffcult to solve, but if it is already in this dict you can't do it

Comment: Its already in the dictionary as 1,Measurement

Answer (score 1):

**Parse file to dictionary**

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    test_dict  = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().split(':')                 # split on ':' after removing whitespace at end of line
        test_dict[line[0].strip()] = line[1].lstrip()   # remove whitespace around key and 
                                                        # left space before value
        
# Show results
print(test_dict.get('ModeName'))                        # Output: 1," Measurement"
```

**File a.txt**

```
ModeName : 1," Measurement"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the example that you shared is with the usage of dictionary.

Valid usage would be

```py
test_dict = {
    "ModeName":[1, "Measurement"],
    }

x = test_dict.get("ModeName")
print(x)
```

This will print the value `[1, "Measurement"]` as the value of x

Comment: Actually my file which has this Mode Name has value as ModeName : 1," Measurement" only. Its a file I cant change

Comment: what is your source file type?